# Why does GPG Encrypt/Decrypt fail between different versions of GnuPG?

Tags: ubuntu, encryption, gnupg, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have 2 servers that will be passing data between them, one is Ubuntu and the other is Red Hat. Using the already installed versions on each, Ubuntu is 12.04 with gnuPG 1.4.x and Red Hat is Enterprise 6.1 with gnuPG 2.0.x, I can't decrypt going from Ubuntu to Red Hat.

I'll be using PHP to encrypt/decrypt using the gnuPG extension on the Ubuntu server. The Red Hat server will be accessing gnuPG through shell out of CGI scripts.

I created public/private keys on Red Hat, exported the public key. Imported it into Ubuntu and signed it. I then encrypted a file on Ubuntu, copied it to the Red Hat server and attempted to decrypt it.

I'm getting this response

```
gpg -d tocyn.gpg
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: decrypt_message failed: Unknown system error
```

Not sure where to go with this as I haven't been able to find much info on what this response means. Is it not possible to do this between the 2 different versions? I may have misunderstood, but I thought they were virtually the same.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you have Ubuntu 1.4.x because that does not seem right.  What version of gnuPG is installed on each system?

Comment: Those are the gnuPG versions, not the OS versions. I'll add the OS versions to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both recent versions of GnuPG 2.0.x and 1.4.x are fully compatible. This should not be the problem, verify that the data was transferred correctly (eg. using checksums).

Anyway: Debian-derivatives like Ubuntu install both GnuPG 1 and 2, where `gpg` is GnuPG 1.4.x and `gpg2` GnuPG 2.0.x.

From GnuPG 2's man page:

> `gpg2`  is  the  OpenPGP  part of the GNU Privacy Guard (GnuPG/MacGPG2). It is a tool to
>   provide digital encryption and signing services using the OpenPGP standard. `gpg2`  features  complete key management and all bells and whistles you can expect from a decent
>   OpenPGP implementation.
>
> In contrast to the standalone version `gpg`, which is more suited for server and  embedded  platforms,  this  version is commonly installed under the name `gpg2` and more targeted to the desktop as it requires several other modules to be installed.  The standalone  version  will be kept maintained and it is possible to install both versions on
>   the same system.  If you need to use different configuration files,  you  should  make
>   use of something like `gpg.conf-2' instead of just`gpg.conf'.

Comment: Thank you for that answer, which is what I had thought. I have determined there was a problem with the file. Checksums didn't match (which I probably should have checked in the first place). Once I re-posted the file, it worked. The error response through me a bit.

Comment: I get "gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found." too with `apt-key add fileWithKeys`, just installed also gnupg2 but nothing changed

Comment: This is a unrelated question, please post it as one. And if possible, include the output of `gpg --list-packets < fileWIthKeys`.